# How to Center Main Menu in Rehub Theme on Desktop/Laptop only?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm new to everything and recently I made a website where I want to center align the main menu. I spent hours trying to find an option to do so but there isn't any.

The site address is: https://fleaprice.com/

I do not want anything about the top menu just the main menu. I want it center-aligned on bigger screens.

I checked all the theme options, read all the possible solutions listed here on this site and tried them all, almost all, but nothing seems to work.

Any help will be very much appreciated. I started my site in Wordpress because I read you do not need any coding knowledge, but now I realize you definitely need to have some knowledge.
Thanks a lot to everyone in advance.

Comment: Best would be if you could add some of the solutions you already tried, so you could get better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to your theme's Custom CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.main-nav.white_style {
    text-align: center;
}
nav.top_menu ul li {
    float: none;
}}
```

Comment: Please click on the gray tick mark and upvote this answer.

Comment: I did but since I am new, my upvote won't show up but the system says it is recorded